# How to execute variable in text/nvarchar SQL Server from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

```
dim sal as double = 20000
```

Table:

```
------------------------------
NO. code       formula
-----------------------------
1   101        sal * (0.2/100)        
2   102        sal * (0.1/100)  
--------------------------------
```

How to execute the formula, stored as text/nvarchar in a SQL Server column, in my ASP.NET code?

Comment: you query is not clear to me can you please elaborate ?

Comment: have record in table, i want to execute this record like this sal * (0.2/100) at field formula value sal is  20000, how get value sal * (0.2/100) = or 20000 * (0.2/100) if do it looping in asp.net / vb.net, thank

Comment: this cannot be possible inside the field you have apply that formula in your code(sp/C#/vb.net) and save the value in table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just mean how you can display the formula embded by the sal as text not as number i suggest you

```
select NO,code,'"+sal+"'+'*'+formula From Table
```

And if you mean how you can use sal to calculate in the query i suggest you

```
select NO,code,"+sal+"*formula From Table
```

if you using variables in formula just change Formula to the variables for Example :

```
select NO,code,'"+sal+"'+'*'+'(0.2/100)' From Table
```

OR

```
select NO,code,"+sal+"*(0.2/100) From Table
```

iwish this help you brother

Comment: can't running well error when execute "Additional information: Conversion from string "select ,'" to type 'Double' is not valid, Input string was not in a correct format.thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you have a formula that is already stored in a table as a string, and you want to get that formula into your ASP.NET application and execute it within the code.

if that is the case, then the fastest way to do it is just execute the formula within SQL Server, substituting the variables, then get the value from there.

if `sal` is already stored within the formula (same as the one that you've provided in your example) you'll need to do something like this :

```
Dim sal as double = 20000
Dim returned_value As String = ""

Dim sql As String = "SELECT formula FROM FormulaTable WHERE Code = 101"

    Using connection As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
        command As New SqlCommand(sql, connection)

        connection.Open()
        Dim formula As String = command.ExecuteScalar().toString()
        connection.Close() 

        sql = "SELECT " + formula.Replace("sal", sal.toString())

        connection.Open()
        returned_value = command.ExecuteScalar().toString()

        connection.Close()
    End Using
```

The example above, will get the formula and replace `sal` with a parameter `@sal` and save that formula in `formula`. Then, we just switch the query, and give the parameter the value of `sal` that we already have in our code, and call `command.ExecuteScalar()` to save the value inside `returned_value`.

Now, `returned_value` is the result of that formula, you can cast it as double or whatever your code requires.

Comment: The latter would have a lot of trust on the table. If anyone could change the value of `formula` in the table, or `INSERT` new rows, then it would be open to injection.

Comment: @Larnu, come to think of it, I couldn't think of another safer approach(maybe someone else will ? ) , so I deleted it. Thanks again.

Comment: can't display result from sal * (0.2/100) just show returned_value @sal * (0.2/100)  result sal * (0.2/100) is 40

Comment: @ahmadsubuhanlubis my bad, forgot to add `"SELECT "` prefix before formula. so the formula should be like `SELECT @sal * (0.2/100)` and the ExecuteScalar will evaluate it and return `40` as string.

Comment: i have try not change, result returned_value =  @sal*(0.2/100) but not evaluated @sal*(0.2/100) = 40

Comment: @ahmadsubuhanlubis check the updated code see if it works now with you.

Comment: @iSR5 not work evaluated result  returned_value  is        
 sal*(0.2/100). thank

Comment: @ahmadsubuhanlubis could you put a snapit of your code + a couple of rows of the actual data in the formula table?